# SharePoint 2013 Alternate Access Mappings to add additional external and internal URL

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, sharepoint, internal-dns, sharepoint-2013

I'm very new to SharePoint administration.

Here's my scenario.

I have a sharepoint, that I'm migrating. I'll call the current sharepoint "oldsharepoint", and the one I'm migrating to, "newsharepoint".

The **oldsharepoint** is currently accessible from inside and outside our environment by going to `sharepoint.mydomain.com`. I eventually want that URL to go to our **newsharepoint**, but for now, I just want to set up an alternate URL to our **oldsharepoint**.  For example, I want to be able to go to `sharepoint.mydomain.com` and `oldsharepoint.mydomain.com` and they both go to my **oldsharepoint**.

I've already added the NS records to my external DNS as well as my internal DNS, but they just spin, which makes sense.  I found the Alternate Access Mapping, and here's what it looks like (except the port isn't actually 120):

```
https://externalsite1.mydomain.com | Default | https://externalsite1.mydomain.com
https://externalsite2.mydomain.com | Default | https://externalsite2.mydomain.com
https://sharepoint.mydomain.com:120| Default | https://sharepoint.mydomain.com:120
https://sharepoint.mydomain.com    | Default | https://sharepoint.mydomain.com
```

I'm guessing if I just added another two lines, like these below, it would work, but I really don't want to break our current setup, just add another URL that goes to the same thing.

```
https://oldsharepoint.mydomain.com    |Default| https://oldsharepoint.mydomain.com
https://oldsharepoint.mydomain.com:120|Default|https://oldsharepoint.mydomain.com:120
```

Is that correct, assuming that I have the DNS records set correctly?  Or will this break my current setup?

Comment: What did you try here? Migrate the same sever from an old hardware to an new one? The it would be easier to take over only the content dbs and leave nearly as verything else on the same config.